# Comparison of two network graphs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I have two network graphs but placing both of them next to each other is the easiest way to compare if the graphs are small. But as the graph grows, it is making hard for the user to compare the views. I wanted to know the best way to merge two graphs and show the comparison.
[image]

In the above picture it can be seen that no of nodes are same but the way they are linked is different.

I would like to know how to present the compared data.

Any ideas about different views to present such comparison using d3.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to apply force layout or similar method for drawing graphs (that would draw the graph in a fashion similar to the on in the picture in your question). Instead, I wold like to suggest using circular layout for both graphs (similar to chord diagram):

[image]

This visual example is made for other purposes, but similar principles could be applied to your problem:

- Layout all vertexes on a circle, in equidistant style (if there are some vertices belonging only to one of two graphs, they can be grouped and marked different color)
- If there is a link between two vertices in both graphs, connect them in one color (lets say green)
- If there is a link between two vertices in one graph only, connect them in appropriate color, dependant on a graph (lets say red and purple)

This method scales well with number of vertices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you VividD. I will try with all the network size and check if it conveys the information without confusion.

Comment: VividD i am trying to do chart with d3.js like image you posted. Do you have a live example somewhere?

Comment: Ups, i just found it - http://ccsb.vanderbilt.edu/ccsb/files/ccsb/circos/ccsb2013.php

Answer (score 1):

Following methods for network comparison could be useful in the current scenario:

[NetConfer, a web application](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12915-020-00781-9)

[Nature Scientific Reports, an article guiding comparisons](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-53708-y)

[CompNet, a GUI tool](https://web.rniapps.net/compnet/)